# Difference between Apple's Thunderbolt ethernet adapters?

Tags: thunderbolt, ethernet

Apple seems to make (at least) two different Thunderbolt ethernet adapters.  One is the "MD463LL/A".  Another is the "MD463ZM/A".

Is there any functional difference between them?  Is one better than the other?

Answer (score 3):

I think there are no differences in the hardware, just the regional identifier for the product. There might be differences in the packaging however. Here in Eastern Europe the ZM model is being sold.

Here is an incomplete list of country codes (unconfirmed, [source](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5785800)):

- AB - Egypt, Saudi Arabia, United Arab Emirates
- B - Ireland, UK, also used for some replacement phones
- C - Canada
- CZ - Czech Republic
- DN - Austria, Germany, Netherlands
- E - Mexico
- EE - Estonia
- ER - Ireland
- FB - France, Luxembourg
- FD - Austria, Liechtenstein, Switzerland
- GR - Greece
- HN - India
- IP - Italy
- J - Japan
- KH - Korea
- KN - Norway
- KS - Finland, Sweden
- LA - Colombia, Ecuador, El Salvador, Guatemala, Honduras, Peru
- LE - Argentina
- LL - USA
- LZ - Chile, Paraguay, Uruguay
- MG - Hungary
- MY - Malaysia
- NF - Belgium, France, Luxembourg
- PL - Poland
- PO - Portugal
- PP - Philippines
- RO - Romania
- RS - Russia
- SL - Slovakia
- SO - South Africa
- T - Italy
- TA - Taiwan
- TU - Turkey
- X - Australia, New Zealand
- Y - Spain
- ZA - Singapore
- ZP - Hong Kong, Macau, Malaysia

Here is another [article](http://www.ilounge.com/index.php/articles/comments/about-ipad-product-codes) showing explaining Apple product codes.